# Observing audio glitch issues when calling SetSpeakerPhoneOn(true) called more then once in Android 12?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Android 12: Calling application.

**SetSpeakerPhoneOn ** API : which uses **setCommunicationRouteForClient ** API to set the speaker as active device(on/off).

We observe audio glitch when multiple times **SetSpeakerPhoneOn ** method is getting called.

Calling application is working fine in Android 9 but not on Android 12.

Where speaker is set on/off using set force usage way (Android 9).

Looking for any fix in Android 12 from Google side.